# How to resolve the following error, TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'float'

Tags: python

```
m.addConstrs( Xtr[t, r] <= (discount_ranges[r+1]-.99)*Otr[t, r] for t in range(T)
                                        for r in range(R))

m.addConstrs( Xtr[t, r] <= (discount_ranges[r+1]-.99)*Otr[t, r] for t in range(T)                                             
                                        for r in range(R))
```

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'float'

Comment: It's telling you that `discount_ranges` contains strings (or at least, a string).  Examine `discount_ranges`, find the string(s), and then try to figure out how they got there.  Then you can fix it.

Comment: As @Tom Karnez said, the problem is with `discount_ranges`. You can probably fix the problem by replacing `discount_ranges[r+1]-.99` with `float(discount_ranges[r+1])-.99` or removing any currency signs before converting`discount_ranges` to a float.